# Namespace not found for Custom C# attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, asp.net-core-3.1

We have a Model that is passed from a web page as json and uses model building in our controller to resolve the properties within our .Net Core 3.1 server.  We want to decorate some properties of that model with a custom attribute so that a "helper" method can perform a transformation on the specified property in our Controller.

When we have NO attributes on our model, everything compiles and works fine.

We have created a class for this model (LoginModel) and decorated a property with our custom attribute [Courier].

```
namespace THO.Demo.API.Models
{

    public class LoginModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Courier(foo: "secret")]
        public string Secret { get; set; }
        [Courier]
        public string PIN { get; set; }
    }
}
```

We have created a class for the Custom Attribute

```
namespace THO.Demo.API.Models
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class CourierAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        private string foobar;
        public CourierAttribute(string foo)
        {
            foobar = foo;
        }

        public CourierAttribute() { }
    }
}
```

When I try to build our project, I get the following errors:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'CourierAttribute' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Courier' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Both of these files are "side by side" in the same project and in the same namespace.  I have tried naming the Attribute "MyCustomAttribute" with the same issue.  When (In VS2019) I click on the attribute, I see a reference and can "jump" to it, so it appears that at least VS knows they are there, but the project will not compile.

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding, also restarting VS? Often this results from a bad dirty code detection in VS.

Comment: Try to clean project, close Visual Studio, delete `.vs` hidden folder, open Visual Studio, rebuild the project again.

Comment: I closed VS 2019, did a Clean Solution, did a Rebuild Solution and no joy.  I still get the same two errors.

Comment: I dropped back to the command line.  I closed VS, did a dotnet clean. did a dotnet build. Same error... :(

Comment: check if both projects target the same .net Framework, if not they become kind of invisible to each other.

Comment: In addition clear cache if you use ReSharper: `ReSharper → Options → General → Clear caches`. Then reopen Visual Studio, clear and rebuild solution.

Comment: We are not using Resharper.  And both of these files are in the same project which is a .Net Core 3.1 Web API project. - The errors point to the line in the "model" where we attempt to decorate the property.

Comment: Did you accidentally set the attribute file to something else than `BuildAction` = `C# compiler`?

Answer (score 0):

Our way of organizing projects is to keep all of our models ({projectRoot}/Models) in a folder and namespace.  We also created a folder for "Attributes" ({projectRoot}/Attributes) where we put our attribute class.  When I moved the "LoginModel" from our Models folder into the root folder of the project, the compiler was able to find the attribute (even when we leave the Attribute class in its own folder).  This makes no sense, as all we did was move the file.  We did not change the namespace.  This seems to be a work around, but it does break our project organization.  (BTW, when we do NOT have a property decorated with an attribute, the model is found and compiles correctly).
Update - the "not found" issue was in a separate project (oops) with a link to the LoginModel.  Once we looked carefully at the eaxact error message and added a link to the Attribute class, everything works.

Lesson learned - CAREFULLY examine the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was cleaning the solution, deleting the obj and bin folders, as well as the hidden .vs folder in the local project files, and after that, compiling again.

Probably at some point in the creation of controllers and attributes, I either copied and pasted an example file or created a new empty one, and Visual Studio might have gotten confused with the references.

By following the steps above, it is forced to generate the automatic files again.